# Куда тире ставить?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

`Я не знал, что оливки на самом деле фрукт.`

Или *на самом деле* заменяет тире?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• "Куда тире ставить?"
Ответ: я думаю, что никуда.

• "Или *на самом деле* заменяет тире?"
Ответ: сочетание *на самом деле* (в значении *в действительности, фактически*) тире не заменяет, оно просто относится к сказуемому "фрукт". Именно поэтому тире и не ставится.

> **Примечание.** Обычно тире не ставится: <...>
> **4)** если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит вводное слово, иногда — наречие, союз, частица...
> **5)** если перед сказуемым стоит относящийся к нему второстепенный член предложения...

Правильно: *Я не знал, что оливки на самом деле фрукт.*

Вот образец постановки тире (между подлежащим и сказуемым ничего нет):

*Я не знал, что любовь — зараза,

Я не знал, что любовь — чума.

Подошла и прищуренным глазом

Хулигана с ума свела.*
Сергей Есенин

[Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92) (Розенталь)

Answer (score 1):

Возможны **варианты:**

(1) *Я не знал, / **что оливки** / на самом деле **фрУкт**.*

(2) *Я не знал, /  **что олИвки //** — на самом деле **фрУкт**.*

Постановка тире зависит от наличия **паузы** и расстановки **ударений.**

Также в качестве варианта:

(3) *Я не знал, / **что оливки на сАмом деле** // — растущий на деревьях фрУкт.*

**Примечание.** Предложение (2) в плане интонационного равновесия делится фактически на две фразы. Предложение (3) нужно дополнительно **распространить**, чтобы отнести "на самом деле" к подлежащему.